# What i can do to convert files and folder to array bytes?

Tags: java

I have a problem converting any type of files into a series of bytes in Java.

I used it:

```
//source file
String sourceFile = "C: /Users/Desktop/hello.txt";
File fi = new File (sourceFile);
//convert file
byte [] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes (fi.toPath ());
System.out.println (fileContent);
```

I can't convert every type I want of any folder containing files to this series?  Can you tell me how I could do that? Is there a way to convert any type or should I change each type differently?

Comment: I wonder what your problem with the post code is/was. Is it this [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](//stackoverflow.com/q/409784)

Comment: No .. I want to put a picture or file or document or folder and turn it into a matrix of bytes!

Comment: Edit your question and add an example of your "matrix of bytes".

Answer (score 0):

you can put your file into a string and then use the getBytes() method

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileToBytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file=new File("put your file path here");
        Scanner fileScanner =new Scanner(file);
        byte[] bytes;
        String s="";
        while (fileScanner.hasNext()){
            s+=fileScanner.next();
        }
        bytes=s.getBytes();
        System.out.println("Array " + bytes);
        System.out.println("Array as String" + Arrays.toString(bytes));
    }
}
```

more information in: https://netjs.blogspot.com/2016/09/converting-string-to-bytearray-java.html

Comment: I can put any type .. such as image,file,text,folder,video ..?

Comment: no it is just for string.to convert a picture visit: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-file-into-an-array-of-bytes/

Comment: This was my question which concerns that there is a special treatment for each type .. but I did not find a way to convert a folder containing the files to an array of bytes .. Do you know how?

Comment: you can compress the folder,make a zip file and then convert it to array but if you can't manage that you should get the folder directory and select all files then convert it.you can use file.getParent() method to get the parent folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a given image file

```
public byte[] extractBytes (String ImageName) throws IOException {
 // open image
 File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
 BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

 // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
 WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
 DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

 return ( data.getData() );
}
```

Explore more about ImageIO and Raster at
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html

> From Docs :
>
> public class Raster extends Object 
>   A class representing a rectangular
>   array of pixels. A Raster encapsulates a DataBuffer that stores the
>   sample values and a SampleModel that describes how to locate a given
>   sample value in a DataBuffer. A Raster defines values for pixels
>   occupying a particular rectangular area of the plane, not necessarily
>   including (0, 0). The rectangle, known as the Raster's bounding
>   rectangle and available by means of the getBounds method, is defined
>   by minX, minY, width, and height values. The minX and minY values
>   define the coordinate of the upper left corner of the Raster.
>   References to pixels outside of the bounding rectangle may result in
>   an exception being thrown, or may result in references to unintended
>   elements of the Raster's associated DataBuffer. It is the user's
>   responsibility to avoid accessing such pixels.